# Log4j2 XML system file separator

Tags: java, log4j2

Is there a way in the log4j2.xml file to use the OS's file separator when creating paths.  I know in Java this can be referenced by File.separator.   I haven't seen a way to this in the log4j2 configuration docs.  Thanks.

Comment: If I remember correct, I think we always need use "/" as file separator in the log4j2.xml file and log4j2 takes care of handling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have a solution looking for a problem.  I use "/" in all my Log4J configurations, Win, Mac or Linux, with no issues at all.  Naturally, "\" doesn't work on the latter two.

Comment: That's what I came across too in order handle all operating systems.  I just didn't like the mixed slashes in Windows I was see in the debug output.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This ${sys:file.separator}

https://github.com/mulesoft/HowTo-Series-Examples/blob/master/aggregate-api-howto_1.0.0/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml